# Unable to run the angular application. Getting error No such file exists robots933456.txt

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-teams

I am running the angular application in Microsoft Teams and deploying it on Azure.

But it's not running up as it is looking for the robots933456.txt route.

It wasn’t the case before today.

Please guide me on how to proceed further.

On running the app the logs shows:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include more details; currently you've only included some log output. Also, please edit to include properly-formatted text of your log output (and any additional code you add), not images of text. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important.

Comment: Go to <website-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net and follow the path /wwwroot/configuration and verify that file exists there.

Comment: @gaurav - could you please check [Upload your app in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/apps-upload)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The error was natively on my side nothing to do with the above but pretty much seen and raised by people so thought of sharing below:**

After doing some research figured out I can safely ignore this message. `/robots933456.txt` is a dummy URL
the path that App Service uses to check if the container is capable of serving
requests. A 404 response simply indicates that the path doesn't exist, but
it lets App Service know that the container is healthy and ready to respond
to requests.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/32472