# Getting a 404 for GET /robots933456.txt

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

In Application Insights(Azure) under failures, there is a failed request for GET /robots933456.txt with 404 response. I am not making this request, but it pops up in my failures. This requests happens randomly, maybe once a week or biweekly.

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Recommended google search: `robots933456.txt` . It is a good practice for tech problems in general to take a distinctive part of a message and try it in a search engine first.

Comment: Google search did not help.@teapot418

Comment: Did you not see this page? https://blog.suddenelfilio.net/azure-app-services-and/ or the info on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?tabs=debian&pivots=container-linux?

Comment: Really? Mine gave me https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/includes/app-service-web-configure-robots933456.md as first result, which seems to be the answer. or further down https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?tabs=debian&pivots=container-linux which also is one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to run the angular application. Getting error No such file exists robots933456.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68161861/unable-to-run-the-angular-application-getting-error-no-such-file-exists-robots9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can safely ignore this message. /robots933456.txt is a dummy URL path that App Service uses to check if the container is capable of serving requests. A 404 response simply indicates that the path doesn't exist, but it lets App Service know that the container is healthy and ready to respond to requests.

via https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/includes/app-service-web-configure-robots933456.md